# PHP array trick

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to build a specific array

I get those arrays from a MySQL query

```
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute(array());
foreach($result as $row)
{
  $test[$i]['case'] = $row[0];
  $test[$i]['name'] = $row[1];
  $test[$i]['task'] = $row[2];
  $test[$i]['current'] = $row[3];
}
```

> echo var_dump($test)

```
array (size=32)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'case' => string '174' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'Bone Tumor' (length=10)
      'task' => string '201006' (length=6)
      'current' => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'case' => string '174' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'Bone Tumor' (length=10)
      'task' => string '207001' (length=6)
      'current' => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'case' => string '174' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'Bone Tumor' (length=10)
      'task' => string '205003' (length=6)
      'current' => string '0' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      'case' => string '174' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'Bone Tumor' (length=10)
      'task' => string '209002' (length=6)
      'current' => string '1' (length=1)
```

I want to regroup the cases and name (which are always by 4) and finish with this

```
array ()
  0 => 
    array ()
      'case' => string '174' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'Bone Tumor' (length=10)
      array ()
        'task1' => string '201006' (length=6)
        't1_current' => string '0' (length=1)
        'task2' => string '207001' (length=6)
        't2_current' => string '0' (length=1)
        'task3' => string '205003' (length=6)
        't3_current' => string '0' (length=1)
        'task4' => string '209002' (length=6)
        't4_current' => string '1' (length=1)

  1 => 
    array ()
      'case' => string '182' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'Cranioplasty' (length=10)
      array ()
        'task1' => string '201006' (length=6)
        't1_current' => string '0' (length=1)
        'task2' => string '207001' (length=6)
        't2_current' => string '0' (length=1)
        'task3' => string '205003' (length=6)
        't3_current' => string '0' (length=1)
        'task4' => string '209002' (length=6)
        't4_current' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Should I change my initial way to get the query directly from the SQL ?

Comment: What? Why not just change the way you build your array so it matches yor desires?

Comment: I would recommend a more flexibly structure: `{test:[{case: 182, name: 'Cranioplasty', tasks: [{id: 201006, current:0},{id: 207001, current: 0}]}]}`

Comment: Also what have you tried to resolve this yourself? It's better to ask "how can I fix this?" not "how do I do this?" questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options.

First use loops

```
foreach($result as $row)
{

  // skip duplicates
  $flag = false;

  foreach($test as $row1)
  {
     if($row[0] == $row1['case'])
     {
         $flag = true;
         break;
     }
  }

  if($flag)
      continue;

  $test[$i]['case'] = $row[0];
  $test[$i]['name'] = $row[1];


  // Fill tasks

  $test[$i]['tasks'] = array();

  foreach($result as $row1) 
  {
      if($test[$i]['case'] == $row1[0])
      {
          $test[$i]['tasks'][] = array('task' => $row1[2], 'current' => $row1[3]);        
      }
  }
}
```

Second option is to execute SQL query to get list of all cases. Then execute queries for each case to get all associated tasks. Assuming you have one table **Cases** with columns

```
id | case | name | task | current
```

Here is how code can look like

```
$sql = 'SELECT c.case, c.name FROM Cases c GROUP BY c.case;';

$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute(array());

foreach($result as $row)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT c.task, c.current FROM Cases c WHERE c.case = '.$row[0].';';

    $tasks = $db->prepare($sql);
    $tasks->execute(array());

    $test[] = array('case'  => $row[0], 
                    'name'  => $row[1],
                    'tasks' => $tasks);
}
```